# Clamav make freeze to laptop

Tags: freeze, clamav

I ran a virus check on my Ubuntu 22.04 laptop  with `sudo clamscan -r / -l /home/max/clamlog.txt` and the machine froze completely. I have to turn it off by pressing the power button for 6 seconds.

Is this normal and what can be done about it?

[image]

Comment: Try to exclude some directories. For example: `sudo clamscan -r -i --exclude-dir="^/sys" --exclude-dir="^/proc" --bell /`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you!

```
sudo clamscan -r --exclude-dir="^/sys" / -l /home/max/clamlog.txt
```

Worked good!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/127B6.png)

Comment: You should also add `--exclude-dir="^/proc"--exclude-dir="^/dev" because `/proc` is not persistent storage and doesn't need to be scanned, and `/dev` is ephemeral and not normal files for scanning.